# Matlab: Dynamically creating a function based on parameter

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

I have an anonymous function like this:

```
  F = @(xy) (2*r(ti,1) .* hypot(xy(1)-BS(1,1), xy(2)-BS(1,2)) + (hypot(xy(1)-BS(1,1), xy(2)-BS(1,2))).^2 ...
                  +2*r(ti,2) .* hypot(xy(1)-BS(2,1), xy(2)-BS(2,2)) + (hypot(xy(1)-BS(2,1), xy(2)-BS(2,2))).^2 ...
                  +2*r(ti,3) .* hypot(xy(1)-BS(3,1), xy(2)-BS(3,2)) + (hypot(xy(1)-BS(3,1), xy(2)-BS(3,2))).^2 ...
                  +2*r(ti,4) .* hypot(xy(1)-BS(4,1), xy(2)-BS(4,2)) + (hypot(xy(1)-BS(4,1), xy(2)-BS(4,2))).^2 );
```

I need to convert this to something dynamic like shown below so that function will have a repeating part based on the paramater I provide:

```
 for m=1:n
     F = @(xy) (2*r(ti,1) .* hypot(xy(1)-BS(m,1), xy(2)-BS(m,2)) + (hypot(xy(1)-BS(m,1), xy(2)-BS(m,2))).^2 +F );
```

With anonymous function I cannot do this though. Is it possible to create something that will construct the function for me based on a paramater ?

Comment: Should be something like `hypot(xy(1)-BS(:,1), xy(2)-BS(:,2))` using the colon operator.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for your comment could you please elaborate on that a little ?